# Creating DOM XML - trying to resolve the 'nbsp' entity problem

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to create XML record. I started with this:

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

Now I should add this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE page SYSTEM "http://gv.ca/dtd/character-entities.dtd">
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Could you be more precise. What language are you using... where does DomDocument come from... how is that related to &nbsp;

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of an error: DOMDocument::loadXML() Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity. To correct this I have to put an extra line just after the first line of XML <? xml ..> This is the mentioned additional line: <!DOCTYPE page SYSTEM "http://gv.ca/dtd/character-entities.dtd">.

Comment: @Loic, DOMDocument is a [PHP built-in](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: DOMDocument functions add the complete tag: <tag></tag> I need to add this: <someTag> without ending </someTag>

Comment: @Charles thanks for pointing it out. It was unclear that he was using php... @chrisiek <!DOCTYPE> isn't a tag it's a declaration if I'm not mistaken with the term. Though the answer below might be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's PHP, you could consider using `DOMImplementation::createDocumentType` and `DOMImplementation::createDocument`. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domimplementation.php)